# httpOnly Session Cookie + Servlet 3.0 (e.g. Glassfish v3)

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-6

By default, Glassfish v3 doesn't set the httpOnly flag on session cookies (when created as usual with `request.getSession()`).

I know, there is a method `javax.servlet.SessionCookieConfig.setHttpOnly()`, but I'm not sure, if that's the best way to do it, and if yes, where the best place would be to put that line.

BTW, of course it *can't* be done in the servlet itself (e.g. in init()):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC1426: 
Unable to configure httpOnly session tracking cookie property for 
servlet context /..., because this servlet context has already been initialized
```

---

Generally, I would prefer to use a configuration option e.g. in web.xml.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is supported via a Servlet 3.0 `web.xml` (see [`web-common_3_0.xsd`](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-common_3_0.xsd)):

```
<web-app>
  <session-config>
    <cookie-config>
      <!--             
        Specifies whether any session tracking cookies created 
        by this web application will be marked as HttpOnly
      -->
      <http-only>true</http-only>
    </cookie-config>
  </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! (I had only looked in web-app_3_0.xsd, and didn't realize, that the schema uses `<xsd:include schemaLocation="web-common_3_0.xsd"/>`)

Comment: @chris_l You're welcome. I wasn't aware too, I noticed that while googling :)

Comment: How can I declare the web-common_3_0.xsd in my web.xml? I upgraded my web.xml to 3.0 <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

Answer (score 3):

You can also add `<secure>true</secure>` to boost the security.

```
<session-config>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only> 
        <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

Comment: The secure tag is sending me a ViewExpiredException for some reason. What am I missing?