# Not able to add more than 2 values in cookies

Tags: http, servlets, cookies

Hi I am new to java servlets. I was trying to implement simple shopping cart problem using cookies. In my web page I ask user to input a product name that she can add to her cart.

Web page:
Simple text input (product name)
and a Button (add to cart)

Upon clicking the button, the web page displays the cart values.

I am experiencing a strange problem. It works fine for less than 3 values. When I try to add third value, it's only displaying the most recently added two values. For example if I add products a, b and c respectively. It displays b and c only.

Cart Servlet code:

```
String name = request.getParameter("productname");

Cookie cookie = new Cookie("product", name);
cookie.setMaxAge(100 * 60);     
response.addCookie(cookie);


Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
names.add(name);

if (cookies != null) {
    for (Cookie c: cookies) {
        if (c.getName().equals("product")) {
            names.add(c.getValue());
        }
    }
}

PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
for (String item: names) {
    writer.println("<h4>" + item + "</h4>");
}
```

index.jsp:

```
<form method="post" action="Cart">
 <input type="text" name="productname" value="Product name">
 <input type="submit" value="AddToCart">
</form>
```

I have spent so many hours to figure out what's wrong in it. but I couldn't find any mistake to explain this strange behavior. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior came from the way how your client (browser) and server handle cookies with the same name.

> "Several cookies might have the same name but different path
>   attributes."

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html

So in your case it is basically the same cookie (based on name and path) which is updated constantly.

So what happens in your case: Basically, the browser returns cookies to the servlet by adding fields to HTTP request headers. Assuming that your first product was named `a` and you are sending your second product with the name `b`, your cookie-header looks like

```
Cookie:JSESSIONID=BCC7050AE82AEA1A4B9BED1174424A92; product=a
```

and your form-data

```
productname:b
```

The server receives the request and a new `Cookie` is created and added to the `HttpResponse` cookie list. The list containing two cookies named product is correctly printed in your response. Since the servlet sends cookies to the browser by using HTTP response headers and your cookies are the same, only an update takes place.

```
Set-Cookie:product=b; Expires=Sat, 23-Dec-2017 11:23:53 GMT
```

As a consequence the next request only contains the information regarding product `b` and product `a` disappears.

Comment: @f1I2 Does that mean I should use a different name for cookie every time a product is added into the cart ?

Comment: In fact I am wondering how do websites implement shopping cart ? If I use http sessions they get lost once the browser is closed. That's why I used cookies so that they can stay longer. But with cookies there is this capacity problem, oracle docs say only 20 cookies are supported for each web server. Which means its a very precious resource to be used.

Comment: @assasinC The session itself is identified by a cookie which by default lives as long as the browser is open. You basically want a session cookie which lives longer than this default one. This [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693180/session-lost-when-closing-the-browser) describes how to do this.

Comment: That's exactly what I did as told in the article. I am using cookie api and added to the response and then getting cookies from the request. But the problem here is, how should I use a cookie for adding multiple cart items. Because if I keep the same name it gets replaced with the existing one, but if I make a different name for each cart item then soon cookies will get exhausted. One way I can see is to put it in a delimited string. So that every time I add a new item in cart, i just append its id to the existing cookie value.

Comment: In my previous comment I tried to explain how the HttpSession ( https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) in conjunction with a _session cookie_ works. In my opinion the HttpSession is the right choice for your uses case. HttpSessions have an unique identifier that maps them to specific users. This identifier can be passed in the URL or saved into a specific _session cookie_, By default the _session cookie_ and the HttpSession get lost once the browser is closed, but you can change this [setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16885023/7246467)

Comment: @f1I2 I still don't understand how can I solve this problem with sessions. How will I make my session to persist even after the browser is closed. In the article it suggests to use cookie API. Let's say I have two users A and B. There are total 10 products in my website. A adds first 5 products in his cart and B adds other 5 in his cart. Now should I use different name of cookie for each different item. Which means total 10 cookies for two users. This is not scalable. I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

I found that following piece in web.xml doesn't invalidate session even after closing the browser. Thanks to fI12 for suggesting the link of [Session Lost when closing the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693180/session-lost-when-closing-the-browser).

```
<session-config>
   <session-timeout>11520</session-timeout>
   <cookie-config>
     <max-age>11520</max-age>
   </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

Using cookies for shopping cart is not a scalable solution. Sessions are the way for this.