# Jetty httpOnly cookies configurarion like on Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, cookies, jetty, httponly

I have Tomcat server on my localhost and on deploy server is Jetty. I use Spring 2.5 with Spring Security 2.0 (Servlets are 2.5). I want to secure session id of our users. I have used these directives to set Tomcat to use HttpOnly cookies.

```
<context useHttpOnly="true">
...
</context>
```

And all works fine (on tomcat). Now I want to do the similar thing on Jetty. Is it possible? Or is it possible to manage it only in application context?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to easily upgrade to Jetty 8, which supports Servlet 3.0. There you have a standard way for that configuration. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033349/httponly-session-cookie-servlet-3-0-e-g-glassfish-v3/3033731#3033731) for how to do it in web.xml.

Comment: I can´t upgrade to Jetty 8 due to fact that server is in a company and administrator won´t  upgrade it :( Any other idea?

Comment: For posterity, perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968217/making-jsessionid-cookie-be-httponly-in-jetty-7