# HttpServletResponse. Is there a way to make cookies secure and/or http-only without using response.setHeader

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

Is there a way to make cookies secure and/or http-only without using `response.setHeader` like this:

```
response.setHeader("Set-Cookies", 
   "name1=value2; Path=/path; Secure; HttpOnly," +
   "name2=value2; Expires=Sun, 03-Jun-2012 23:00:56 GMT; Path=/, etc.");
```

But using some built-in functionality?

P.S. I'm not talking about session cookies, but custom cookies an application uses.

Comment: If you use Servlet 3.0, check [this question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033349/httponly-session-cookie-servlet-3-0-e-g-glassfish-v3

Comment: This is different. I can setup secure session cookies. I'd like to make other cookies secure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html). There's a [`HttpServletResponse#addCookie()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#addCookie%28javax.servlet.http.Cookie%29). Your particular example can be solved as follows:

```
Cookie name1 = new Cookie("name1", "value1");
name1.setPath("/path");
name1.setSecure(true);
name1.setHttpOnly(true);

Cookie name2 = new Cookie("name2", "value2");
name2.setPath("/");
name2.setMaxAge(secondsUntil3Jun2012);

response.addCookie(name1);
response.addCookie(name2);
```